# Trying to calculate the distance between the position of two objects

Tags: java

I have these two instance variables which are set within the constructor of the object to be:

```
    (int)(Math.random()*100);
```

The two instance variables are:

```
    private double xPos;
    private double yPos;
```

The class is called Soldier and I have three other classes that inherit from Soldier, (only the constructor at the moment)

The output I am getting at the moment is:

My name is: Cavalier I am at position: (45.0,56.0)

My name is: Crossbowman I am at position: (15.0,91.0)

My name is: Halberdier I am at position: (67.0,8.0)

I am trying to calculate the distance in the x and y positions of the objects

The method I am currently trying is:

```
    protected Soldier distanceBetween(Soldier x, Soldier y){
        double distBetween = (x.xPos - y.xPos)+(x.yPos-y.yPos);
        return this;

    }
```

The method I am trying to achieve is where two objects that inherit from Soldier are taken into the distBetween paremeters, 
for example I use the names: 
halberdier,
cavalier and 
crossbowman.

When I call this method:

```
    cavalier.distanceBetween(cavalier,crossbowman);
```

I want it to calculate the distance between the x and y coordinates

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Do you think `(x.xPos - y.xPos)+(x.yPos-y.yPos)` will return correct distance ?

Comment: I was thinking of a way to achieve it but no, I cannot see the logic behind it as much

Comment: formula is [(x2 -x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2]^0.5 and not (x2-x1) + (y2-y1)

Comment: How would I implement this into my set of variables? note that xPos = x axis and yPos = y axis

Comment: The distance formula you've mentioned is known as the "Manhattan distance." That is, it's the distance when the soldier is constrained to move only north/south or east/west (as if along the streets and avenues of New York). That formula is actually `Math.Abs(x1 - x2) + Math.Abs(y1- y2)` -- you didn't compute the absolute value.   You may, or may not, want the Cartesian distance (distance at the crow flies).  That formula is `Math.Sqrt( ((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)) + ((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)) )`

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but when you are dealing with x and y coordinates, naming your *Soldier* variables `x` and `y` makes even a few lines of code considerably more confusing and harder to read, both for you and for us.  A soldier is not an x coordinate or y coordinate, so don't name it that way.  Better names might have been `soldier1` and `soldier2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely wrong.

You need to return a value, not a Soldier.

This is more general:

```
public static double distanceBetween(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    double dx = Math.abs(x2-x1);
    double dy = Math.abs(y2-y1); 
    if (dx > dy) {
        double r = dy/dx;
        return dx*Math.sqrt(1.0 + r*r); 
    } else {
        double r = dx/dy;
        return dy*Math.sqrt(1.0 + r*r); 
    }
}
```

The `^` operator is not exponentiation; it's XOR.

You can override this method this way:

```
public static double distanceBetween(Soldier s1, Solder s2) {
    return distanceBetween(s1.xPos, s1.yPos, s2.xPos, s2.yPos);
}
```

Since you are having trouble, I'll spell it out for you:

```
/**
 * Distance calc
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 11/1/2015
 * Time: 9:58 AM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462961/trying-to-calculate-the-distance-between-the-position-of-two-objects/33463222?noredirect=1#comment54712511_33463222
 */
public class Soldier {

    public final double xPos;
    public final double yPos;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Soldier s = new Soldier(0, 0);
        Cavalier c = new Cavalier(3, 4);
        System.out.println(String.format("distance: %f10.3", s.distanceBetween(c)));
    }

    public Soldier(double xPos, double yPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }

    public double distanceBetween(Soldier s) {
        return distanceBetween(this.xPos, this.yPos, s.xPos, s.yPos);
    }

    public static double distanceBetween(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        double dx = Math.abs(x2-x1);
        double dy = Math.abs(y2-y1);
        if (dx > dy) {
            double r = dy/dx;
            return dx*Math.sqrt(1.0 + r*r);
        } else {
            double r = dx/dy;
            return dy*Math.sqrt(1.0 + r*r);
        }
    }

    public static double distanceBetween(Soldier s1, Soldier s2) {
        return distanceBetween(s1.xPos, s1.yPos, s2.xPos, s2.yPos);
    }
}

class Cavalier extends Soldier {
    public Cavalier(double x, double y) {
        super(x, y);
    }
}
```

If you want different distance calculation methods (e.g. Euclidian, Manhattan, Pearson, spherical, etc.)  you can have an interface that lets you change it by adding a new implementation:

```
public interface DistanceCalculator {
    double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);
}
```

Now you can easily switch by adding new code rather than modifying existing code.

Comment: The x and y coordinates are random though

Comment: Won't affect this method if you pass the randomly generated values in.  This method is 100% correct; yours is not.

Comment: But how do you pass in a Soldier objects instance variables?

Comment: See my changes.  This is Java 101.

Comment: Struggling?  I wrote it for you.  What's the issue?

Comment: From my Cavalier class for instance how would I implement the override method to calculate distance between Cavalier and Crossbowman classes? which both come with their randomly generated x and y positions?

Comment: Idealy I was trying to get a method that specified the super hero name and then the parameter would calculate it against one superhero such as Cavalier.distancebetween(Crossbowman) which calculates distance between them

Comment: Thank you for this, really helped

Comment: I'm sure it did - I wrote the whole thing for you.  I'd prefer that you accept the answer.

Comment: I did not use the whole thing, I only needed the distance between part of it, in the end I combined the override method.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this member function in your Soldier class.

```
public double ManhattanDistance (Soldier other)
{
    return Math.Abs(this.xPos - other.xPos) + Math.Abs(this.xPos - other.xPos);
}
```

If you want Cartesian -- crow-flies -- distance you need this member function.

```
public double Distance (Soldier other)
{   
    double dx = (this.xPos - other.xPos);
    double dy = (this.yPos - other.yPos);
    return Math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

To use these member functions to get the distance between your `cavalier` and your `crossbowman` you do this kind of thing.

```
 double howFar = cavalier.Distance(crossbowman);
```

or

```
 double howManyBlocks = crossbowman.ManhattanDistance(cavalier);
```

Comment: Your explanation of Manhattan versus Euclidian distance is very good.  It makes me think that an interface DistanceCalculator that could be modified by different concrete implementations might be good.

Answer (score 0):

You have to imagine a right angle triangle ABC. You have the coordinates for A (45.0,56.0) and C(15.0,91.0). You have to get coordinate of B first which is holding the right angle.

Coordinate of B is

> (45.0,91.0)

So AC will be :

`Math.sqrt(Math.pow(91-56)+Math.pow(45-15))`

[image]